# How to decrease the value of a database entry

Tags: mongodb

I have a nodeJS system where a student enrolls for a batch, and so i have a field in the mongodb as `batchSize` which holds maximum number of students in one batch, student can enroll on a batch and `batchSize` should reduce its value

how to write a query to do the same?

Comment: See [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) and use a "negative" value to "decrement" or "decrease".

Comment: awesome, i didn't know about the negative part, thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to uset the findAndModify() method: with a simple update() you could fall into cuncurrency issue: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Batch.update({ _id: data.batch._id }, { $push: { 'students': data.student }, $inc: { currentlySubscribed: 1 } }

Batch.update({ _id: data.batch._id }, { $pull: { 'students': { 'email': data.student.email } }, $inc: { currentlySubscribed: -1 } }
```

Comment: How do I stop it from going negative?

Comment: with min and max values configured in mongoose schema